# Submit Button not Full Height of Container

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a submit button fill the full height of it's container using the code below, however it does not do so.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.test {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div style="float: right;">
    <form method="post">
      <input class="test" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div style="float: left; width: 95%;">
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space!</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3apqb869/1/

Comment: i don't think you can use `height:100%` with out the parent knowing it's own height. Try setting the container height

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that (https://jsfiddle.net/3apqb869/2/) but the issue persists.

Comment: you have to add the height onto the form! [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ho796jp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use flexbox for stuff like this. As long as you're OK with dropping support for IE<=10 it makes styling things like this so much easier. There are also polyfills for it if you aren't.

https://jsfiddle.net/3apqb869/3/

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  //implicit flex-direction: row;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Here's a great guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, it solved my issue! I feel like flex is such a great solution for many problems, but as many answers on this site are from previous years, flex isn't widely spread.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position` for these cases (Supports IE 7 as well, as Flexbox is not supported):

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 70px;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <form method="post">
      <input class="test" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div style="float: left; width: 95%;">
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space!</p>
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space!</p>
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space!</p>
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space!</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: Preview]

Comment: Ehh this takes the submit button out of the flow of the page so the p would run underneath it. Not ideal.

Comment: @Harangue Giving `padding-right` fixes it. Ideal case.

Comment: So now you have to know the exact width of the button. Still not ideal. ;)

Comment: @Harangue Ha ha... :) But Flexboxes aren't supported in all the browsers.

Comment: https://github.com/10up/flexibility gives you IE 8 and up. If you want more support than that more power to you

Answer (score -1):

You can use `display: table` combined with `table-cell` to achieve the required behavior [**Submit button will require absolute positioning** and the **width has to be fixed** so that the button text doesn't overflow and get truncated].

*Pros:*

`display:table` and `display:table-cell` has a solid support in modern as well as classic browser (I wouldn't say old)

*Cons :*
Person who down voted should have commented on that.

```css
.container {
  background: #fff;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

.container >div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.submit-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div >
    <p>Hello! This is an example... by the way, I'm from outer space! I'm from outer space!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-wrapper">
    <form method="post">
      <input class="test" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3apqb869/10/

Comment: From your fiddle, it seems like the submit button is vertically centered and doesn't have a height of 100%;

Comment: Modified CSS to allow submit button to occupy the entire height